# Error con SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

Creé un SQLSERVER y al momento de querer correr mi codigo js para enlazarlo al servidor, aquí el código que tengo:

```
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    const Request = require('tedious').Request;
    const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

    const config = {
      server: "PC03\\FICHASDSC",
      authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sa',
            password: '123456'
        }
    },
    options: {
        databse: 'mastrer'
    },
    }

  const connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected')
    }
  })
```

ESTO ME DEVOLVIÓ

> { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to PC03\FICHASDSC:1433 -
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND PC03\FICHASDSC
>       at ConnectionError (D:\fichas-db\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
>       at Connection.socketError (D:\fichas-db\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1222:28)
>       at Connector.execute (D:\fichas-db\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1061:21)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.dns.lookup [as callback] (D:\fichas-db\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:138:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:17)   message:    'Failed to connect to PC03\FICHASDSC:1433 - getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND PC03\FICHASDSC',   code: 'ESOCKET' }

Comment: ENOTFOUND significa que el cliente no se pudo conectar. Seguro que Node puede resolver PC03 al servidor que deseas?

Comment: El servidor es PC03, pero lo complejo. (Soy nuevo en Sql-Server) No me deja configurar realmente el nombre del servidor o al menos conectarme a localhost.

Comment: Revisa que el servidor permita conexiones TCP/IP